# Python Drop all instances of Feature from DF if NaN thresh is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Using `df.dropna(thresh = x, inplace=True)`, I can successfully drop the rows lacking at least `x` non-nan values.

But because my df looks like:

```
          2001     2002     2003    2004

bob   A   123      31       4        12
bob   B   41        1       56       13
bob   C   nan      nan      4        nan

bill  A   451      8        nan      24
bill  B   32       5        52        6
bill  C   623      12       41       14

#Repeating features (A,B,C) for each index/name
```

This drops the **one row/instance** where the `thresh=` condition is met, but **leaves the other instances of that feature.**

> ### What I want is something that drops the *entire feature*, if the `thresh` is met for any one row, such as:

```
df.dropna(thresh = 2, inplace=True):

           2001     2002     2003    2004

bob    A    123      31       4        12
bob    B    41        1       56       13

bill   A    451      8        nan      24
bill   B    32       5        52        6

#Drops C from the whole df
```

*wherein `C` is removed from the entire df, not just the one time it meets the condition under `bob`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample looks like a multiindex index dataframe where index level 1 is the feature `A, B, C` and index level 0 is names. You may use `notna` and `sum` to create a mask to identify rows where number of non-nan values less than 2 and get their index level 1 values. Finall, use `df.query` to slice rows

```
a = df.notna().sum(1).lt(2).loc[lambda x: x].index.get_level_values(1)
df_final = df.query('ilevel_1 not in @a')

Out[275]:
         2001  2002  2003  2004
bob  A  123.0  31.0   4.0  12.0
     B   41.0   1.0  56.0  13.0
bill A  451.0   8.0   NaN  24.0
     B   32.0   5.0  52.0   6.0
```

---

**Method 2**:
Use `notna`, `sum`, `groupby` and `transform` to create mask `True` on groups having non-nan values greater than or equal 2. Finally, use this mask to slice rows

```
m = df.notna().sum(1).groupby(level=1).transform(lambda x: x.ge(2).all())
df_final = df[m]

Out[296]:
         2001  2002  2003  2004
bob  A  123.0  31.0   4.0  12.0
     B   41.0   1.0  56.0  13.0
bill A  451.0   8.0   NaN  24.0
     B   32.0   5.0  52.0   6.0
```

Comment: It is multi-indexed, you are correct. Your method looks like it will work, trying it now... Thank you!!

Comment: Upon application to my actual df, I have encountered less success... Am I not applying it correctly?  Moreover, should I need to put these within a loop? I still believe your answer is correct, but I do not think I am applying it right. The structure of my actual df and this one are identical, except that there are more than one series ('C') with all NaN values.

Comment: @Alex: `thresh` option in `dropna` is the number of `non-NaN`. So, you want to drop rows basing on the number of `non-NaN` or the number of `NaN` ?

Comment: Please forgive the confusion. I believe your answer is the correct method, but when I run ```df.reset_index()
pd.DataFrame(Counter(df.series).keys(), Counter(df.series).values())``` I see that there is a different number of series counts for each series, when I would expect them all to be the same.

Comment: I will link to the reposted question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621000/drop-series-from-entire-df-if-row-has-at-least-2-nan-values

Answer (score 0):

Keep only the rows with at least 5 non-NA values.

> > > df.dropna(thresh=5)

thresh is for including rows with a minimum number of non-NaN