# Drop Series from Entire DF if Row has at least 2 NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Having an issue with dropping all instances of a given series from the whole DF given a `.dropna(thresh= x)`, that I thought had been [Previously Resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593901/python-drop-all-instances-of-feature-from-df-if-nan-thresh-is-met)

#### Dataframe:

*Note that it is Multi-indexed*

```
          2001     2002     2003    2004

bob   A   123      31       4        12
bob   B   41        1       56       13
bob   C   nan      nan      4        nan

bill  A   451      8        nan      24
bill  B   32       5        52        6
bill  C   623      12       41       14

#Repeating features (A,B,C) for each index/name
```

This drops the **one row/instance** where the `thresh=` condition is met, but **leaves the other instances of that feature.**

> #### drop the series from the *entire df*, if the `thresh` is met for any one row, such as:

```
df.dropna(thresh = 2, inplace=True):

           2001     2002     2003    2004

bob    A    123      31       4        12
bob    B    41        1       56       13

bill   A    451      8        nan      24
bill   B    32       5        52        6

#Drops C from the whole df
```

### The solution I am using:

```
m = df.notna().sum(1).groupby(level=1).transform(lambda x: x.ge(2).all())
df_final = df[m]
```

### Does not seem to work for the entire DF

> **I believe I am just not applying it correctly... Any advice would be appreciated on how to fully implement this^ or the other solution:**
>
> > ```
> > a = df.notna().sum(1).lt(2).loc[lambda x: x].index.get_level_values(1)
> > df_final = df.query('ilevel_1 not in @a')
> > ```
>
> Please note that in the actual DF, there will be more than one series that meet the nan threshold and will therefore need to be removed...

## Further Explanation on Expected Result:

using

```
from collections import Counter

pd.DataFrame(Counter(df.series).keys(), Counter(df.series).values())

#Where series is the index_level_1 (A,B,C etc.)
```

I would expect an output of:

```
2   A
2   B
...

#Where the count of the series keys is the same for each series
```

Comment: could you add into the sample data the case where you think it doesn't drop it as you want? Again, you want to drop by counting the number of `NaN` or number of `non-NaN` ?

Comment: @Andy L. This is correct, however, it now seems to be working correctly... Please allow me some time to better organize what I think might be going on so that I can return with a more concise example/problem statement. Thank you for your patience

Comment: @AndyL. I discovered what was going wrong. Your solution was working correctly (thank you again). My issue occurred when I used a `.pivot`, without setting the `dropna = False`. Therefore, the series instances that met the threshold were already being removed, BEFORE the threshold could be met which would have otherwise triggered the removal of the entire series from the df. I am a bit embarrassed. Thank you for your time, assistance, and patience.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you figure it out :)